# How to take backup or export sqlite database from react native

Tags: android, database, react-native, sqlite, path

I am new to react native, I have developed an offline android app using [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage) package.

I want to take a backup or export the created database.

Is there any way to export database or to get database location/path in android,
I have searched lot for it but not get any appropriate answer for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked SQLite backup api ? https://sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: I checked, but how can I integrate that into react-native app to export or to get back up database file?

Comment: Hi, I have same problem, how can we export ( or get backup) database file in react native? Is there a documentation that explaine this? Very thanks

Comment: @NihalChandwani Yes!  I used RNFS.copyFile(path, destPath)
         .then(() => { console.log('successfu')}) where path is '/data/user/0/<your.app.package>/databases/<your.name.database>'; and destPath is RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath  + "/" + "NewdatabaseDati" +".db";

Comment: @NihalChandwani In the path don't add the .db extention